FORTRAN90 test suite for Project Euler
The intent of this test file is to go through each of my Project Euler solutions and see if they:

return the correct answer, and
do so in under 60 seconds (unless expected otherwise).

I am using this as a way to learn fortran, so any feedback on performance, clarity, or design would be incredibly helpful. I have no prior experience with fortran.
Relevant links:

Git repo
Website with docs
Link to utils.f90, which defines AnswerT and get_answer(), though the intent should be mostly clear

test.f90
program test
    use utils
    use Problem0001
    use Problem0002
    use Problem0006
    use Problem0008
    use Problem0009
    use Problem0011
    use Problem0836

    implicit none
    integer(kind=4), dimension(:), allocatable :: problem_ids
    logical(kind=1), dimension(:), allocatable :: long_runtime
    integer :: num_problems
    
    num_problems = 7
    allocate(problem_ids(num_problems))
    allocate(long_runtime(num_problems))
    problem_ids = (/ &
        001, &
        002, &
        006, &
        008, &
        009, &
        011, &
        836 &
    /)
    long_runtime = (/ &
        .false., &
        .false., &
        .false., &
        .false., &
        .false., &
        .false., &
        .false. &
    /)

    call process_problems(problem_ids, long_runtime)
    deallocate(problem_ids, long_runtime)

contains

    subroutine process_problems(problem_ids, long_runtime)
        integer(kind=4), dimension(:), intent(in) :: problem_ids
        logical(kind=1), dimension(:), intent(in) :: long_runtime
        type(AnswerT) :: expected, answer
        integer(kind=4) :: i
        integer :: first_count, second_count, count_rate, count_max, tmp
        real :: time_elapsed

        ! Loop through each problem
        do i = 1, size(problem_ids)
            print *, "Processing Problem ID: ", problem_ids(i)
            if (long_runtime(i)) then
                print *, "  This problem will take more than 60 seconds."
            end if
            expected = get_answer(problem_ids(i))
            call system_clock(first_count, count_rate, count_max)
            answer = select_function(problem_ids(i))
            call system_clock(second_count, count_rate, count_max)
            if (expected%type /= answer%type) then
                print *, "  Error: type mismatch between expected answer and returned value"
                select case (answer%type)
                    case (int64t)
                        print *, "  Returned: int (", answer%int_value, ")"
                    case (stringt)
                        print *, "  Returned: string (" // answer%string_value // ")"
                    case (errort)
                        print *, "  Returned: error"
                end select
                select case (expected%type)
                    case (int64t)
                        print *, "  Expected: int (", expected%int_value, ")"
                    case (stringt)
                        print *, "  Expected: string (" // expected%string_value // ")"
                    case (errort)
                        print *, "  Expected: error"
                end select
                stop 3
            end if
            select case(expected%type)
                case (int64t)
                    if (expected%int_value /= answer%int_value) then
                        print *, "  Error: problem ", problem_ids(i), " failed!"
                        print *, "  Expected Answer  : ", expected%int_value
                        print *, "  Solution returned: ", answer%int_value
                        stop 1
                    end if
                case (stringt)
                    if (expected%string_value /= answer%string_value) then
                        print *, "  Error: problem ", problem_ids(i), " failed!"
                        print *, "  Expected Answer  : ", expected%string_value
                        print *, "  Solution returned: ", answer%string_value
                        stop 1
                    end if
                    deallocate(answer%string_value, expected%string_value)
                case (errort)
                    print *, "  Error retrieving answer!"
            end select
            tmp = second_count - first_count
            if (tmp < 0) then
                tmp = tmp + count_max
            end if
            time_elapsed = real(tmp) / real(count_rate)
            if (.NOT. long_runtime(i) .AND. time_elapsed > 60.0) then
                print *, "  Error: problem ", problem_ids(i), " timed out!"
                print *, "  Solution took    : ", time_elapsed, "s"
                stop 2
            end if
            print *, "  Completed        : ", problem_ids(i), "in ", time_elapsed, "s"
        end do
    end subroutine process_problems

    type(AnswerT) function select_function(problem_id) result(answer)
        integer(kind=4), intent(in) :: problem_id

        answer%type = int64t
        select case (problem_id)
            case (1)
                answer%int_value = p0001()
            case (2)
                answer%int_value = p0002()
            case (6)
                answer%int_value = p0006()
            case (8)
                answer%int_value = p0008()
            case (9)
                answer%int_value = p0009()
            case (11)
                answer%int_value = p0011()
            case (836)
                allocate(character(len=14) :: answer%string_value)
                if (.not. allocated(answer%string_value)) then
                    print *, "  Memory allocation failed for string_value. Returning error type"
                    answer%type = errort
                else
                    answer%type = stringt
                    answer%string_value = p0836()
                end if
            case default
                print *, "Unknown problem ID!"
                answer%type = errort
        end select
    end function select_function

end program test


The language has been called Fortran, not FORTRAN for many decades. It is unlikely that you are actually using Fortran 90, the compilers do not even consider this revision because it contained several problems and was quickly replaced by Fortran 95. In particular, thi file extension .f90 does not mean Fortran 90 but any free-form source.

Using magic constants like 4 or 8 for the kind values is ugly and will fail to compile for some compilers in their default setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170239/fortran-integer4-vs-integer4-vs-integerkind-4#3170438  I, personally, find writing the full kind=something unnecesarilly long and always remove the optional kind= so the proper integer(iknd) where iknd is a named integer constant is even shorter (and the constant name can also be even shorter).

Working on updating my docs/code to address both of these. Thank you! ♥️

Generally this looks like beautiful modern Fortran code, nicely presented.
DRY
            select case(expected%type)
                case (int64t)
                    if (expected%int_value /= answer%int_value) then
                        print *, "  Error: problem ", problem_ids(i), " failed!"
                        print *, "  Expected Answer  : ", expected%int_value
                        print *, "  Solution returned: ", answer%int_value
                        stop 1
                    end if
                case (stringt)
                    if (expected%string_value /= answer%string_value) then
                        print *, "  Error: problem ", problem_ids(i), " failed!"
                        print *, "  Expected Answer  : ", expected%string_value
                        print *, "  Solution returned: ", answer%string_value
                        stop 1
                    end if

Consider turning int_value into a formatted string_value
so you can use a single set of prints to report on the failure.
The business of having select_function() dynamically allocate string space
which caller is responsible for deallocating seems like it's on the fragile side.
The C and Java folks having been duking out that one for years.
Given that you have a statically compiled set of problems with constant
solutions, it might be feasible to punt by using a static buffer
that is big enough for the configured set of problems.
malloc fail
We call allocate() from several different places.
It's not clear why we need to test if (.not. allocated())
in just one place.
Surely the other allocations could similarly fail, right?
Consider writing a helper which bails with fatal error
if an allocation attempt is seen to fail.
SRP
If you feel you need to preserve the current type-safe duplicated behavior,
at least push that functionality down into a helper which has just
a single responsibility.
quadratic cost
function get_answer(id) result(answer) is a beautiful helper; good job with that.
Nice contract.
But with \$N\$ problems, the API + implementation leads to \$O(N^2)\$ cost.
Caching would be the obvious way out of it.
Accept a burden of \$O(N)\$ linear memory complexity, and
retain a memory-resident cached copy of the .tsv file which you can index into.
Or adopt a revised API which lets the caller stream through
the contents of an answers input file that we keep open until the end.
Given the more than 900 Project Euler questions,
quadratic re-reading implies a cost of around 800,000 re-reads,
or still a wasteful 400,000 if we terminate early.
More generally, statically linking against 900 functions
seems daunting on several levels.
Consider exploring other approaches.
Maybe a driver script should assemble the needed code components,
compile them, execute, and put the result in an output.csv file
for later analysis.
Maybe dynamic linking is indicated.
A given child subprocess could execute all Euler functions or just
a subset of them, even just a single function.
And then we fork off additional children for further answers.
timeout
Making long_runtime a boolean vector seems like the wrong design choice.
Better to define an "expected" or "maximum" elapsed running
time for each problem.
If you'd care to keep it vague,
maybe define such running times as powers of \$2\$,
with the smallest limit being \$2^5\$ seconds.
This program's output speaks of "timeout", but it doesn't
actually time out a miscreant while .true. loop.
It patiently waits for the target code to eventually return,
and then scores it as "incorrect" if it exceeded the time limit.
Consider using SIGALRM to terminate badly behaved code early.
Consider running such code in a child process,
to which you can send SIGTERM if needed.
multiple cores
Rome wasn't built within a day,
and 900 solution routines won't all run within a millisecond.
If you have actual elapsed run times that (a subset of) problems
were seen to consume on a previous run, and you're forking off children to run them,
then you're in a good position to keep all \$C\$ of your cores busy.
Expected time for this run is roughly the observed time from previous run.
Sort by descending expected time, and fork off \$C\$ child tasks.
Upon seeing a task complete, fork off the next one.
That way we do the big ones first and have just little ones at the end,
avoiding the "straggler effect" where many idle cores
wait for one busy core to eventually finish.

Given the lazy allocaten in modern OS's, testing if allocate failed will in practice fail to detect that there was actually not enough memory. The program will crash at the access anyway. I wouldn't bother.

@Vladimir, that's very dependent on the environment in which you run.  For example, I normally run programming-challenge code with a sensible `ulimit -v, to prevent harming more important processes.  That usually has the effect of preventing such over-allocation, but does mean that we need to deal with allocation failure.

Okay, I've addressed a number of these things in my codebase now!

I am checking all allocate() calls now, not just the ones I wrote after learning I could.
I refactored get_answer so that it is caching the results, and no longer needing those excess reads
I now have a script which generates select_function(), which should reduce dev time overhead
I'm working to move the comparison and printing logic to a function, which should make that more clear

